# Python Pandas - Combining DataFrames Independently to Spreadsheets

Tags: python, pandas

My problem that im working towards is combining data frame below each other but keeping them independent of each other. For example:

```
df1 = data1.pivot_table(index=pd.to_datetime(data1['Date']), 
                              columns=['State','City'], values=metric) :
State       L.A.     L.A.   L.A.
City        Arcadia  Bell   Durate
2/22/2018   2.05     3.07   1.96
2/25/2018   4.82     2.56   3.14
3/2018      2.51     3.45   3.02

df2 = data2.pivot_table(index=pd.to_datetime(data2['Date']), 
                              columns=['State','City'], values=metric) :
State       G.A.     G.A.      G.A.
City        Athens   Atlanta   Macon
2/22/2018   1.56     3.25      1.97
2/25/2018   3.92     3.66      1.28
3/2018      3.61     1.25      3.42
```

When I concat them the data is paired side by side like so:

```
State       L.A.     L.A.   L.A.     G.A.     G.A.      G.A.
City        Arcadia  Bell   Durate   Athens   Atlanta   Macon
2/22/2018   2.05     3.07   1.96
2/25/2018   4.82     2.56   3.14
3/2018      2.51     3.45   3.02

2/22/2018                            1.56     3.25      1.97
2/25/2018                            3.92     3.66      1.28
3/2018                               3.61     1.25      3.42
```

My question is if there is way to format the data so that it can end up looking like this

```
State       L.A.     L.A.   L.A.
City        Arcadia  Bell   Durate
2/22/2018   2.05     3.07   1.96
2/25/2018   4.82     2.56   3.14
3/2018      2.51     3.45   3.02
State       G.A.     G.A.      G.A.
City        Athens   Atlanta   Macon
2/22/2018   1.56     3.25      1.97
2/25/2018   3.92     3.66      1.28
3/2018      3.61     1.25      3.42
```

Thank you!

Comment: That would make it really hard to work with in `pandas`, is there a specific reason you'd want to do this? There are probably more efficient ways to organize your data

Comment: Its more two show people the data. Normally we have google do the formatting but it eats up a lot of the execution time.

Comment: I'd recommend having separate **columns** for `date`, `state`, `city`, and `value`, it should still be easy to read when you show it to people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you consider saving each dataframe to a single `.xlsx` file, and simply place each frame below the previous one?

```
import pandas as pd

save_path = "path\\to\\the\\excel_file.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(save_path)
all_frames = [df1, df2, dfn]  # all of your dataframes

counter = 0
for df in all_frames:
    df.to_excel(writer, startrow=counter, index=True)
    counter += df.shape[0]
```

This should result in a `.xlsx` file that contains the desired output, as you have above:

```
State       L.A.     L.A.   L.A.
City        Arcadia  Bell   Durate
2/22/2018   2.05     3.07   1.96
2/25/2018   4.82     2.56   3.14
3/2018      2.51     3.45   3.02
State       G.A.     G.A.      G.A.
City        Athens   Atlanta   Macon
2/22/2018   1.56     3.25      1.97
2/25/2018   3.92     3.66      1.28
3/2018      3.61     1.25      3.42
```

Comment: Thanks! i did something similar where i saved it as a .csv and just appended the data below each one. Ill have to look into the start row parameter, seems like it could come in handle.